# Low pass filter in the input of ADC supply

Tags: adc, analog, low-pass

Attached figure shows a LPF connected to the input of an ADC preset in the microcontroller. Can anyone please explain why an inductor is connected in parallel with the resistor.

Regards
Hari
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Actually the resistor is in parallel with the inductor ;-)

Without the resistor the inductor and capacitor will *resonate* at a certain frequency which you want to avoid as this just needs to filter the supply. A resistor in parallel with the inductor will suppress this resonance.

Comment: Uhm, you're right resonate, I used the wrong word there. Changed that.